# Why does my VBA Loop start backwards?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

My code is currently as :

```
Sub delsheets()

For i = 1 To 9 Step 1

    Worksheets(i + 3).Delete

Next i

End Sub
```

My workbook has 12 sheets in total.

I have stepped into the macro and see that the macro executes by deleting the sheets backwards and in step 2 even though i have specified step 1- i.e progression of deleteion: sheet 12, sheet 10, sheet 8, sheet 6, sheet 4.

I have no idea why this happens, and i'd like for my macro to execute via the normal way.

I'd greatly appreciate a breakdown of why this is happening!

Comment: every time you delete a sheet with a low index number, indexes of higher sheets are re-numbered

Answer (score 5):

You want to do this backwards.

When using the index number instead of the sheet name it uses the order of the tabs along the bottom.

So when iterating forward, when you delete sheets(4), what was sheets(5) now becomes sheets(4) and gets skipped.

So it skips every other 1.  Change you for loop to go 9 to 1 Step -1. and it will not skip any sheets.

Either use the sheet name to delete or loop backwards:

```
Sub delsheets()

For i = 9 to 1 Step -1

    Worksheets(i + 3).Delete

Next i

End Sub
```

If the Name of the sheets are `1, 2,...` then use this:

```
Sub delsheets()

For i = 1 to 9

    Worksheets(Cstr(i + 3)).Delete

Next i

End Sub
```

Changing the number to a string will delete the sheets named 4,5,6,...,12

Comment: Also `For i = 0 to 8` and `Worksheets(12 - i).Delete` is possible... While it is like a direct `Step -1` most ppl don't like loops with a `Step` <>1. I at least for my part (looking at speed) would use something less understandable like `Sheets(Application.Transpose(Evaluate("ROW(4:12)"))).Delete` ;P

Comment: Thank you for your help!